# Is there any way to get stderr or stdout of AWS lambda when AWS lambda is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to see AWS lambda stdout and stderr on when my code is running.

Is it possible to get it?

So How to do it?

I need a help.

Comment: You could also potentially use a custom logger within your Lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your Lambda has permissions, all output is written to [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html) in the region that your Lambda is deployed to.

You can use this to see any output, or errors/exceptions that are thrown by your application in near real time.

Comment: According to this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html# lambda should automatically log to cloudwatch.  In my case, I'm not able to see the logs for my function name (which works fine) and I dont know why.  Any clues?